# Steps to apply patch in Informix database

Tags: informix

Can anyone suggest me the steps to apply patch (patch upgrade) on IBM Informix database. Please suggest the best practices available. If possible share me the URL or any documents.

Answer (score 2):

It's a big topic.  A good deal depends on how the server is currently set up — there are setups that make it hard and others that make it easier.  Another major factor is your level of risk averseness.  You need to make an assessment of the amount of down-time you can afford.  Also, how often have you practiced recovery from backups — it probably won't be necessary, but you need to cover your bases.

I am assuming you're using Informix Dynamic Server, not Informix Standard Engine (SE).  Upgrading SE is much, much simpler.

#### Preparation

Before you install, make sure you have a good, recent, level 0 archive of your system.

Also, make sure you know where your software is installed, and which disks and files it uses.

#### Route 1: Simple, but potentially risky

- Make sure you have a backup copy of $INFORMIXDIR.
- Take down the servers that are currently running using this $INFORMIXDIR.
- Install the new version of the software over the existing software.
- Restart the server

Why is this risky?  At issue is what happens if anything goes wrong, and also the length of time the server(s) is (are) down.  If you bring up the server and decide something is wrong and you wish to go back to the old version, you have to take servers down, reinstall the old software (copy off the backup?), and then bring the (old version of the) server back up.  This takes time.  This isn't often a problem, but it has happened on occasion over the last couple of decades.

#### Route 2: Parallel install

This is the way I do it, but I ensure that my system is set up so that this is easy to do.  In particular, the file names used to identify the chunks used by the server are symlinks to the actual storage.  This makes it easier to move or replace storage when necessary — you change the symlink instead of having to modify the server configuration.

- Create a new directory (e.g. `/opt/informix.new`) and install the new version of the software in it.
- Copy the configuration files from the current $INFORMIXDIR (e.g. `/opt/informix`) into the new one.
- Ensure any other files or directories under the old $INFORMIXDIR that are needed for the new one are copied across or recreated empty.
- Review the parallel setup; as best you can, make sure that when you're ready to switch, everything will work.
- Take the old server down.
- Move the old $INFORMIXDIR to a new name (i.e. `mv /opt/informix /opt/informix.old`).
- Move the new $INFORMIXDIR to the working name (i.e. `mv /opt/informix.new /opt/informix`).
- Restart the server

Why is this less risky?  The primary advantage is that the old software is still on the machine and switching back to the old version is therefore simply a question of undoing the original pair of move commands.  Another major advantage is that the down-time for the system is limited to the time taken to stop, switch directories, and restart the system.

What are the potential downsides?  If you weren't careful enough about copying the necessary files from the old to the new system, you can find yourself missing something critical.

Note that if your chunks are not symlinks, and especially if they are cooked files stored under the old $INFORMIXDIR, you can run into problems.  These are not insuperable; you just have more work to do than simply moving directories.  Do *not* (repeat not) move or copy chunks while the server is running.  They will not (necessarily) be consistent.

Variations?  I usually needed multiple versions of Informix around, so I'd use sets of directories like `/work3/informix/ids-12.10.FC1` and `/work3/informix/ids-11.70.FC4` as the real directories.  I'd then use a standard symlink name as `$INFORMIXDIR`, such as `/opt/informix` which would link to the current version-specific INFORMIXDIR under `/work3/informix` in this example.  (Actually, there were some extra levels of complexity in my setups, but my requirements as an Informix developer were different from those of most customers.). But the key point is that instead of moving directories, I switched a symlink — `rm /opt/informix; ln -s /work4/informix/ids-12.10.FC3 /opt/informix` to use 12.10.FC3 instead of 12.10.FC1, for example.

#### Post-installation

Run a new level 0 archive.

#### General observations

Informix upgrades are usually seamless and smooth.  If there is conversion work to do on the upgrade, the server does it automatically when the new version is brought up.

Be aware of the mechanisms for reverting to an older version of the server if that is found to be necessary.

I've done presentations and/or papers on this in years past at IIUG conferences.  Check out the [IIUG](http://www.iiug.org/) web site, and the IBM Informix [documentation](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSGU8G_12.1.0/com.ibm.welcome.doc/welcome.htm).